# Suggestion for encrypting database files in SQL 2008 Standard Cluster

Tags: sql-server-2008, encryption

I have an SQL 2008 Server configured as a fail-over cluster an have a requirement to have the database files (mdf/ldf) encrypted.  We have tried to use EFS for this but there are a lot of issues doing this and often the file get corrupted and unusable.

Other than using SQL 2008 Enterprise are there any other options you can suggest?